# Position Eigenstates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra, superposition, observables

Suppose that the state of a system can be represented as a superposition of finite position eigenstates $|\Psi \rangle = \sum_{i}c_{i}|x_{i}\rangle$, where each $|x_{i}\rangle$ corresponds to a unique subregion $X_{i}$ of a larger region $X$ so that $\cup X_{i} = X$.

Let A be the observable corresponding to the question "Is the system in the region $X$?"

1. How do you construct A in terms of $|x_{i}\rangle$?
2. Are there any conditions for $|\Psi\rangle$ to be an eigenstate of A?
3. Is A commutable with the position operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's ignore the complications that arise with a continuous basis, since this is really a general question about more general quantum projective measurements.  So, let's pretend that the basis $|x\rangle$ is actually discrete.

Then, since the measurement doesn't distinguish between different values of $x$ that lie in $X$ and doesn't distinguish between different values of $x$ that lie outside of $X$, we can say that there are only two outcomes of the measurement, 1 corresponding to $x\in X$ and 0 corresponding to $x \notin X$. By doing that, we can write down the operator
$$
\hat{A} = \sum_{i\in X} (1)|x_i\rangle\langle x_i| +
\sum_{i\notin X} (0)|x_i\rangle\langle x_i|
=\sum_{i\in X} |x_i\rangle\langle x_i|\,.
$$
This operator represents the "physical observable" that we are measuring here.  Notice that:

1. It's explicitly written in the $|x\rangle$ basis.
2. The conditions for $|\Psi\rangle$ to be an eigenstate of $\hat{A}$ is that it is either a linear combination of states $|x\rangle$ where $x\in X$ or it's a linear combination of states $|x\rangle$ where $x\notin X$.
3. It clearly commutes with $\hat{x}$ because it is diagonal in the eigenbasis of $\hat{x}$.

---

For continuous variables, you really can't talk about the probability of getting a finite (or even countable) subset of the values of $x$.  To get a feeling for what you have to do in this case, we usually think about intervals on the real line.  That is, let's suppose we want an operator that corresponds to the question, "Is the particle in $[a,b]$ or not"? Then, the corresponding operator is
$$
\hat{A} = \int_a^b |x\rangle\langle x|\,dx\,.
$$
This also commutes with $\hat{x}$, and as long as a wave function $\Psi(x)$ has support completely contained in $[a,b]$ or completely disjoint from $[a,b]$, then the corresponding state $|\Psi\rangle$ will be an eigenstate of $\hat{A}$ (in the loosey-goosey physics sense of eigenvectors of operators like $\hat{x}$, because, strictly speaking, they don't actually have eigenvectors in the strict mathematical sense, but that's another story).

Comment: Thanks! Does the 'strict mathematical sense' in which $|\Psi\rangle$ is not an eigenstate of $A$ have to do with the continuous nature of the position states?

Comment: @Torpido Yes. My understanding is that for eigenvalues in the continuous part of an operator's spectrum, there is no eigenvector, but there are *approximate* eigenvectors. The issue, for instance, is that the "eigenvector" of the position operator is $\delta(x-x')$ in position space, which is not part of the Hilbert space.

Comment: The solution is kinda easier than that. Quantum states live in Hilbert space. The eigenvectors corresponding to the continuous eigenvalues of any observable (Hermitian) operator lives in Rigged Hilbert space. We are allowed to do mathematical manipulations using these eigenvectors living in Rigged Hilbert space, as long as we remember that, when we need to deal with quantum states, they cannot be one of these eigenvectors, only wavepackets of them.

Comment: Now, position eigenstates is actually even worse than that. We love to work with position eigenstates in NR QM, but actually SR QFT disallows that. The concept of position eigenstates turn out to violate Lorentz covariance, and this is supremely annoying for everybody.

Comment: Thanks for the addition! Now, I understand that the operator A you defined commutes with the position operator, but is it quite often the case that a system is in an eigenstate of A but not in an eigenstate of B, where [A, B] = 0?

Comment: @Torpido It happens all the time. Chemists like to use the hydrogen-like orbital $p_x$, $p_y$, and $p_z$, which are eigenstates of the total momentum operator $\hat{L}^2$ (corresponding to quantum number $l=1$) but are linear combinations of eigenstates of $\hat{L}_z$ and so not eigenstates of $\hat{L}_z$. Nonetheless, $\hat{L}_z$ commutes with $\hat{L}^2$ (and in fact commutes with the hydrogen Hamiltonian, so $m$ is a good quantum number). There's nothing to stop it from happening. In fact, it will *automatically* happen under measurement of $\hat{A}$.

Comment: That looks like an interesting example, thanks! When two Hermitian operators commute, is there a sense in which they are associated with the same *kind* of properties? Are there any case where two observables do commute but are radically different from the other qualitatively so that they are in no sense the same *sort of* physical quantities?

Comment: Since the commutation relation is an equivalence relation (i.e., reflexive, symmetric, and transitive), I would have expected that the relation partitions the entire space of observables so that any two observables in the same partition shares something interesting in common.

Comment: @Torpido Being commutative is not an equivalence relation!  *Everything* commutes with the identity operator but not everything commutes! So it's not transitive.

Comment: @Torpido As for your first question, there's not kind of nice thing like this, and there are somewhat trivial examples: multi-particle systems.  If you have an electron and a proton in a system, all of the operators corresponding to proton degrees of freedom commute with the operators corresponding to electron degrees of freedom, and so, for instance, electron spin commutes with proton position, electron momentum commutes with proton position, and so on.

Comment: @march Thanks! That's a good point! Barring Identity, is it still not transitive?

Comment: @Torpido. Yep.  First, any scalar multiple of the identity works.  But there are *loads* of examples. It is very much not transitive. Here's one non-trivial example: $\hat{p}_x$, $\hat{x}$, and $\hat{y}$.

Comment: Okay, suppose [A, B] = 0 and [B, C] = 0. 
Then, [A, C] = AC - CA
= A(BC) - (CB)A
= (AB)C - C(BA)
= BAC - CBA
= (BA - BA)C
= 0
Doesn't this hold?

Comment: How did you get this equality: $AC - CA = A(BC) - (CB)A$? Where did the $B$ all of sudden come from? And in this step: $BAC - CBA = (BA - BA)C$, how did you move $C$ past $BA$ in the second term? You don't know that $C$ commutes with $B$, so you don't know that $C$ commutes with $BA$. And so on.  There's no use trying to prove this because *it is not true*.

Comment: Oh I was confused, you're right! Yes, if there is a definite counterexample, there can't be a proof. Thanks!!